# Should my custom ASP.Net 5 MVC 6 Tag Helpers have an asp- prefix?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I've been reading about the new support for Tag Helpers in MVC 6 and now need to create my own. I see that the built in tag helpers for existing HTML elements are all prefixed with "asp-"

For example: 
`<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>`

But what about my own custom tag helpers. Should I also prefix those with "asp-" to show that it is running on the server. Or should this be reserved for framework attributes? Should I create my own project/company named prefix instead?

**Is there any guidance on this subject that I have missed?**

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Taylor Mullen! hopefully that is enough to get it reopened. I actually really want to know the answer before I go and put my custom tag helpers all through my code only to have to change them later. To be honest I don't think there is any official guidance on this at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tag helpers that target [existing HTML elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/elements.html) should preface attribute names with a prefix that indicates the attribute is additive and run on the server. For example, the built in ASP.NET 5 Tag Helpers use the “asp-” prefix. The “asp-” prefix is not considered a reserved prefix, so developers can copy that convention. Some teams will prefer to use their own naming convention to distinguish their Tag Helpers.

If a Tag Helper targets a custom element then attributes should not be prefixed. Custom elements are processed only on the server, so you don’t need the prefix to denote server processing. A good example is the EnvironmentTagHelper. The following markup comes from the *Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml* file created by a new ASP.NET web app.

```
<environment names="Development">
```

See also [Authoring Tag Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring)

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate you clearing this up for me before I get too far with a project.

Answer (score 0):

Each TagHelper targets one or more specific HTML elements or custom tags.

for example take a look [AnchorTagHelper](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers/AnchorTagHelper.cs), You can see, `TargetElementAttribute` is used to associate this TagHelper with the standard HTML a element:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = ActionAttributeName)]
//...
public class AnchorTagHelper : TagHelper
```

So your custom tag helper have its own pre-fixes.

Comment: The MS policy on this is that it's OK to use "asp-" prefix. See my answer below which is going into our TH documentation.

Comment: @RickAnd-MSFT Thanks for your answer :)